# Localhost database works perfectly, hosting doesn't

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, fetch

I am trying my application on localhost. When I am connected to my localhost database, everything works properly. When I change to my hosting database, it throws this error - "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input".

**Working connection:**

```
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_password = 'root';
$db_db = 'film_storage_app';

//set DSN
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $db_host . ';dbname=' . $db_db;
```

**Not working connection:**

```
    $db_host = 'myHost';
    $db_port = 'thePort';
    $db_user = 'theUser';
    $db_password = 'myPassword';
    $db_db = 'myDb';

   //set DSN
   $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $db_host;
   if (isset($db_port)) $dsn .= ';port=' . $db_port;
   $dsn .= ';dbname=' . $db_db;
```

**PDO setup:**

```
//create PDO instance
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

**My JS fetch function which throws the error:**

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('select', 1);

const response = await fetch('process_php.php', {method: 'POST', body: formData});
const ajaxResponseJson = await response.json(); //this line throws it (works correctly on localhost)
return ajaxResponseJson;
```

There is the response I am getting:

```
body: ReadableStream
locked: true
__proto__: ReadableStream
cancel: ƒ cancel()
getReader: ƒ getReader()
locked: (...)
pipeThrough: ƒ pipeThrough()
pipeTo: ƒ pipeTo()
tee: ƒ tee()
constructor: ƒ ReadableStream()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "ReadableStream"
get locked: ƒ locked()
__proto__: Object
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost/film_storage_app/process_php.php"
__proto__: Response
```

**My PHP code:**

```
if (isset($_POST['select'])) {
    $sql = 'SELECT imdbId, title, type, year, runtime, plot, actors, poster, director, genre
                FROM favorite_movies AS fm
                INNER JOIN
                user_movies AS um
                ON fm.imdbId = um.movieId
                INNER JOIN
                users AS u
                ON um.user = u.username
                WHERE user = :user
                ';
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute([
        'user' => $_SESSION['username']
    ]);
    $posts = $statement->fetchAll();

    $favorite_movies = array();

    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        array_push($favorite_movies, [
            'id' => $post->imdbId,
            'title' => $post->title,
            'type' => $post->type,
            'year' => $post->year,
            'runtime' => $post->runtime,
            'plot' => $post->plot,
            'actors' => $post->actors,
            'poster' => $post->poster,
            'director' => $post->director,
            'genre' => $post->genre,
        ]);
    }

    echo json_encode($favorite_movies);
}
```

More info:
I have the exact same database on localhost and on my server. What could be wrong?

Btw, my login system works even on the hosted database. So there is no problem with the database itself.

EDIT: edited my dsn to not include the port (the error remains), included response in question

Comment: Usually this error occurs when the JSON output is empty. You've to check your server logs for errors.

Comment: What the response? Add a `console.log(response);` between `const response = await fetch('process_php.php', {method: 'POST', body: formData});` and `const ajaxResponseJson = await response.json();` or check the Network tab in the browser dev tools.

Comment: `$db_host = 'sql.endora.cz:3317';` must not contain the port https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php. Nitpick: `DNS` should be `DSN`. It stands for Data Source Name and not for Domain Name Service.

Comment: The response is:
body: (...)
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost/film_storage_app/process_php.php"
__proto__: Response

Comment: You can see it there - https://ctrlv.cz/swLR

Comment: `body: (...)` is the most interesting part. Open it and post it as text to your question.

Comment: Done, you can see it in the question body

Comment: I hope for you that are not your real credentials....

Comment: I'm not so experienced with `fetch` and didn't know you can't see the body as plain text in the `response`. Open the tab Network in your browser's dev tools and check the response.

Comment: I was assuming that the credentials aren't real but since you changed them in the question I recommend to change them in your database, too. Questions have an edit history and you can't remove the credentials from the question. If the credentials were real they were wrong.

Comment: @jabaa Now I see the problem, the localhost db returns correct response, the hosted doesn't return anything in the network tab. What could be the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: A wrong configuration. The problem that was fixed in my answer could cause this problem. This question started as a JavaScript question but now it's a PHP backend question. The problem is somewhere in your DB connection.

Comment: @jabaa They were real, but this isn't some important database. I am okay with someone getting into the db (but will change later just to make right). Why do you think they are wrong?

Comment: No, sorry. They are correct. I did a mistake. Now I can connect.

Comment: Yea, I am connecting with them. What could be the problem?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Stack Overflow is not a guessing game. At least now we now the problem isn't in your frontend but in your backend.

Comment: Added PHP code. I think this will be enough (this segment doesn't use any more code). I just thought the PHP code isn't important cause it works on localhost db.

Comment: Have you checked the server logs? There are probably error messages.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I used your credentials and the posted code. I got the results for users `dddd` and `test`. Everything works. The problem is somewhere else. The hosted database works.

Comment: @jabaa Nothing after I fixed the error you posted bellow

Comment: I could send you link to github if you have time and you are willing to look at it (it is not a large app)

Comment: Maybe there are issues with your firewall or network. It's impossible to say. The PHP code works for me. The database works. The credentials are correct.

Comment: Try to create a file with https://wandbox.org/permlink/MO5g9I4YCFfTcSjp and run it on your server with `php movies.php`. It should print a valid JSON encoded list of movies. It works for me. The problem could be the PHP configuration. Connecting to localhost could work without `pdo_mysql` using the Unix Domain socket.

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't understand the app you just send. I uploaded my project here - https://workupload.com/file/FRNSTkBYPqp - couldn't find any online file upload and run code.

Comment: You can be sure that almost all users here won't download and unzip files. I gave you a working PHP script. You can use it to check your system configuration.

Comment: [Here](https://paiza.io/projects/HwLc0jyWbvuHMCjpKGziUg) you can see a working example.

Comment: "Here you can see a working example." - works for me too. And the code is the same I have, now I am really confused, must be error in the js part.  By the way, I really appreciate your help, would be totally lost without your help rn. Thank you a lot man. About the zipped file - I thought I would run it through VM to stay safe.

Comment: FOUND THE ERROR! Gave it some testing and the only thing that is different is $_SESSION['username']. Tried it with 'test' in the original app and it works! Now I just have to figure out why my sessions doesn't work properly. But this is a real progress. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem was in the hosting. Paid version fixed everything.

Answer (score 1):

`$db_host = 'sql.endora.cz:3317';` must not contain the port https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php.

You can configure your connection with

```
$db_host = 'sql.endora.cz';
$db_port = '3317';
$db_user = 'storageadmin';
$db_password = '7Ec3uHUkuQgCEXd';
$db_db = 'moviestorage';

$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $db_host;
if (isset($db_port)) $dsn .= ';port=' . $db_port;
$dsn .= ';dbname=' . $db_db;
```

Or remove the port if it's the default port.

Comment: @David In that case you've probably multiple errors in your code. My answer fixes one of them. Have you checked the actual response the backend is sending to the client? The credentials are wrong. Are you sure you're using the correct credentials?

Comment: Well, thanks for that. The credentials are correct, because my login system works (otherwise it wouldn't I guess). I edited the question, you can see the response I am getting in my fetch function now. The strange thing is everything works perfectly in localhost database. Couldn't the provider be somehow bad?

Comment: @David We already found a breaking error in your code. First we should check your code.